# how to generate this url from a sample with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

i want to rewrite

```
example.com/login?id=login&says=invalid&usr=username
```

request to

```
example.com/login&says=invalid&usr=username
```

and i am using this rules .

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \login?id=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R,L]
```

but it says internal server error (500)

what is wrong with it? even the

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} login\?id=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R,L]
```

do not work .

i tried many thing and no result.
note that login file is not a real file but it have its rule that

```
example.com/login&says=invalid&usr=username
```

works fine.

```
**#loop :**
```

the page

```
example.com/login&says=invalid&usr=username
```

works fine but if system add another thing to it it will show 404
for example if system want to do the same thing again ( adding ?id=login&says=invalid&usr=username to end of address ) it shows 404

```
example.com/login&says=invalid&usr=username?id=login&says=invalid&usr=username
```

Comment: `example.com/login&says=invalid&usr=username` doesn't look like a usual pretty URL. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: The URL you want to convert this to doesn't seem to be valid, did you mean `example.com/login?says=invalid&usr=username`?

Comment: no! i want to 'login&says=invalid&usr=username' replace in address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login[^?]*)\?id=[^&\s]+(&\S*)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [NE,R,L]
```

Comment: thank you . it worked but make a loop . i will add loop problem to my question .

Comment: thanks a lot it worked . i have another question . is there any way that when user request for 'example.com/login&says=invalid&usr=username' just see 'example.com/login' in browser and '&says=invalid&usr=username' functions work ?

Comment: No we cannot hide `&says=invalid&usr=username` from URL and still make it available to `login` page.